# Is it possible for a universal app to have an in-app purchase that works on iPad only?

Tags: ios, app-store

Just what it says on the tin. I'm thinking about releasing a universal (iPhone and iPad) app, and I'm also considering having an in-app purchase that will add functionality, but I think that the functionality is only applicable to the iPad version of the app. Is it within Apple's guidelines to offer an in-app purchase that only works on certain devices?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that's fine. Your universal application can have different features per platform, that isn't against any rules. As long as you don't restrict your IAP to particular devices themselves, then that's fine (i.e. it should be available throughout the **platform**)

The onus is on you to make sure that IAP will only occur on iPads. A simple `[UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` check would suffice.

Comment: Plus you probably wouldn't even show the purchase option on iPhone/iPod...

Answer (score -1):

The [in-app purchase guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/news/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf) specify:

> You must make your In-App Purchase items available to all of the devices registered to
>   a user.

Comment: I don't think that fits here, because it is still available to all iPad devices of the user. If the feature is for iPad and can't be bought on iPhone/iPod, it's ok.

Comment: @jimpic Hmm. I don't think so. Elsewhere in the link from Mike, they say `Consumable items are the one exception to the requirement that your content be available on all the user’s devices. Consumable items are digital items that are used up or disappear after use and can never be reused. Examples of consumable items include virtual poker chips, in-game ammunition, or virtual supplies such as construction materials.`

Comment: That's for cases like in games. You shouldn't buy coins on one device and get X times the amount for X devices you own, but only one instead.

Comment: Possibly a point of contention; the IAP will be available on all devices (as in, he's not purposefully restricting it on particular devices, via UDID or someform or another), but it can only be used and bought on the iPad (note, all the user's iPads). If the functionality were to come to iPhone, then it would automatically become available. @jimpic is correct.